# Smooth scroll in iOS web browsers

Tags: ios, browser, scroll

I recently wanted to use `scroll-behavior: smooth` CSS rule or any other form of the same (eg. `scrollTo` with behavior: smooth) in a web app on iOS but this scroll option is apparently not exposed by the platform, so it is in effect unavailable in any of the browsers like Safari or Chrome for iOS.

Why isn’t this option allowed? Is there any philosophy behind that decision? Or is maybe implementation of this feature on the roadmap already (I didn’t find it)? I found that smooth scroll as an option is implemented in WebKit, but couldn’t find any info on why Apple doesn’t allow you to use it.